# send simple e-mail encoded in iso-8859-1 to iphone with php

Tags: php, ios, iphone, encoding, iso-8859-1

I have experienced problems with iOS devices receiving special characters encoded in ISO-8859-1.

So in order to understand the problem I have created a simple PHP script which sends a very simple encoded message. On all my other e-mail clients it works but on iOS it doesn't.

I need some help to modify this code in order to make it work.

Please don't suggest UTF-8. My application cannot be switched to UTF-8 therefore I'd like to know how to send ISO-8859-1 encoded characters.

This is the code that needs to be modified:

```
<?php    
$recipient  = 'user@domain.com';
$betreff = 'special characters test';
$subject = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>special characters test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Test for special characters encoded in ISO-8859-1</p>  
  <strong>ISO-8859-1:</strong> äöüÄÖÜß<br><br>
  <strong>Entities:</strong>  &auml;&ouml;&uuml;&Auml;<br><br>
</body>
</html>
';
$header  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$header .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
if (mail($recipient, $betreff, $subject, $header)) 
  echo "email has been sent.";
?>
```

Comment: I just noticed: on an iPad it works correctly on an iPhone it doesn't. Strange...

Comment: It also works with personal iPhones. Could be a problem of my corporate environment. Don't really know how to find a workaround if even entities don't work.